# iOS Circular Slider

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, ios7

I want to create a circular slider like below.

[image]

But i want two functionalities in addition.

1) I want to start the slider from any point,but in fig. it starts from 0.

2) I want to include multiple sliders in a single circular black plot.

I'm sharing the link of this project:
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/circularsliderdemo

Can anyone help me to do these functionalities.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not how SO works. SO is for getting help with specific problems. There are other sites like Github where you can post collaborative projects and get help, and places like CodeMentor where you can pay somebody to help you with your project (I participate in both of those.)

What you describe would not be particularly hard for an experienced Cocoa/Cocoa touch developer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at `CAShapeLayer`. You could create a path that is a full circle, and use the strokeStart and strokeEnd properties to only draw part of the circle. You could use core animation to animate between the beginning and the end.

There is an open source custom gesture recognizer on Github that is a one finger gesture recognizer. That would be a good start for detecting and responding to the twirl gesture that such a control would need. **EDIT:** It's called [**KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer**](https://github.com/kirbyt/KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer) (link)

Those are some ideas to help get you started.

I have a project on github called [**iOS-CAAnimation-group-demo**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/iOS-CAAnimation-group-demo) That includes a "clock wipe" animation. The clock wipe works by setting up a shape layer as the mask layer for an image view, installing a full-circle arc that's wide enough to completely fill a rectangular area, and then animate the strokeEnd property of the shape layer to reveal/hide the image view. The clock wipe is much more complex than what you need, but it would give you the seed of what you want. You'd use a shape layer with a much thinner line width, and you would use it as a content layer, not as a mask.

Comment: There's no such thing as a CAPathLayer.

Comment: @matt, sorry, my mistake. I meant CAShapeLayer. (I corrected my answer.) Thanks for pointing out my error.

Comment: Yup, no harm no foul.